# How can I make more than 50 product variation types?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have an online printing shop where each product can have different variations which can change the price. To make different product variations, I have to add all the different variation types as products, then add them to the product display.

It works fine in this way, but I have many variations.

How can I make more than 50 product variation types?

Comment: Move any customizations that don't affect SKU or stock to the line item level, and expose them on the add to cart form. Should help you cut down on the number of variations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Commerce Bulk Product Creation

Consider using the [Commerce Bulk Product Creation](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> ... facilitates the creation of groups of related products in bulk. Product administrators can select a number of options for various fields, and a product will be created for all possible combinations of these values. Out of the box, only list fields are supported for this, but an API exists to enable other types of fields for 'combination creation'.

**Attention**: this module doesn't have an official release yet (only an RC6), though with over 1.600 reported installs, it seems it is pretty stable / trustworthy.

## Commerce Backoffice

Another option to consider is using the [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) module, e.g. because of the ***auto creation of product display nodes***. It provides the backoffice functionality present in [Commerce Kickstart (V2)](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), and contains these sub-modules:

- Commerce Backoffice **Product** (commerce_backoffice_product).
- Commerce Backoffice **Order** (commerce_backoffice_order).
- Commerce Backoffice **Content** (commerce_backoffice_content).

This module (and a few dependencies) provides the rich store owner experience that has made Commerce Kickstart 2 so popular (and prevents that you have to install the entire Commerce Kickstart distribution). And there is a [great video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMZ_VcBan0) about it also.

**Note**: if you use [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice), you most probably also want to use the [Shiny](https://www.drupal.org/project/shiny) administration theme, also used in [Commerce Kickstart (V2)](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Pierre, but my question is about the workload of data-entry, I know that Commerce BO helps with the Product Display part but I still have to add an entire different product because one simple change in an option, like having a different size, so later on I can add it to the product display.

Comment: I understand your "pain", but maybe it helps you're not the ony one. Give me some time to think AbitMORE about this. I wonder (have to do some reaseach) if there could be a way using the "rules" module, something like "if a term gets added to some taxonomy" (event) then "create a corresponding product (maybe by cloning it from some kind of 'template')" (action)

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I think theoretically there should be a module that gives you a functionality to define different sets of `Options` and then you can add it to certain products, for example a Business Card Product can have up to 100 different options that you can add to it. it's still a bit of overload but I can't come up with any better solution, even theoretically! Cheers bro.

Comment: OK, I gave it some more thought, refer to my updated answer (added commerce_bpc now). Curous to hear if that helps ...